Managed package - how to authorize access to orgs
We are attempting to connect one Salesforce org to multiple others (Production / Sandbox) using a web server login flow from a managed package. Our approach involves storing 'refresh_token' and 'access_token' in either custom settings or custom metadata. Is this method optimal, or could it potentially pose security risks.Is there any other ways to store token in salesforce.
If above ways are wrong, please suggest any other alternate ways to connect multiple salesforce org from managed package.

The managed package will be installed on other orgs, and the main one will be making HTTP requests to these orgs, correct?
If so, I would keep the connection data (refresh_token) in Custom Object encrypt it (either via classic encryption or Apex Crypro class), and use Object Level Security to ensure nobody has unauthorized access. Custom Settings and Custom Metadata Types will not add any additional security.

I disagree with the latter. A managed package can define protected custom metadata or custom settings which cannot be accessed from outside the managed package code base.

Personally I would consider storing this data in the managed package's free platform cache partition since it is going to need to be shared across multiple transactions but are all somewhat transient, so must be regularly updated. Obviously, this only works for security reviewed packages.
